# How can i store data on a Javascript chart?

Tags: javascript, charts

I embedded this chart on my Webpage. The problem is that it's not really storing data, for example: if i open the chart at a certain time the chart will start from 0 and i will not be able to see what the chart showed 1 hour before i opened the page.

How can i edit it so that i can see past data?

```
var time = new Date();

var data = [{
  x: [time], 
  y: [rand()],
  mode: 'lines',
  line: {color: '#80CAF6'}
}] 


Plotly.plot('graph', data);  

var cnt = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function() {

  var time = new Date();

  var update = {
  x:  [[time]],
  y: [[rand()]]
  }

  Plotly.extendTraces('graph', update, [0])

  if(cnt === 100) clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: If this code is running server-side, a la node-js, the values will reset every time the server does. If it is running on the client machine, it will reset every time the page is fully reloaded. For persisting data, you need to use some mechanism like storing it in a cookie, writing it to a file, using a database, etc. depending on your use-case.

Comment: Got it, thank you!